# Snaps mounting errors on boot even after removing snaps

Tags: boot, mount, snap

I am using Ubuntu 22.04 lts, i removed snapd from my system and replaced snaps with flatpaks. Now whenever I boot the pc, it shows [these errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1V71P.jpg), but it boots normally and works normally, I just want to get rid of these annoying errors.

(why show me snap mounting errors when I no more use snaps? maybe due to some leftover files or configuration?)

Image Here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1V71P.jpg

Comment: I installed snapd but running 'snap list' says no snap is installed. But the mounting errors still persist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you should have to do is remove the call(s) that tries to mount the snap files at bootup.  These files are contained in the `/etc/systemd/system/` directory.

Remove the snap `.mount` file(s) for the one(s) you don't want.

Example:

```
terrance@terrance-ubuntu:/etc/systemd/system$ ls *.mount
 snap-bare-5.mount
 snap-bitwarden-84.mount
 snap-bitwarden-85.mount
'snap-canonical\x2dlivepatch-146.mount'
'snap-canonical\x2dlivepatch-164.mount'
 snap-code-122.mount
 snap-code-123.mount
 snap-core-14784.mount
 snap-core-14946.mount
 snap-core18-2714.mount
 snap-core18-2721.mount
 snap-core20-1828.mount
 snap-core20-1852.mount
 snap-core22-547.mount
 snap-core22-583.mount
 snap-cups-872.mount
'snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d28\x2d1804-161.mount'
'snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d28\x2d1804-194.mount'
'snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d38\x2d2004-119.mount'
'snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d38\x2d2004-137.mount'
'snap-gtk2\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-13.mount'
'snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1535.mount'
 snap-snapd-18357.mount
 snap-snapd-18596.mount
'snap-snap\x2dstore-599.mount'
'snap-snap\x2dstore-638.mount'
'snap-ubuntu\x2dapp\x2dplatform-34.mount'
 snap-warble-5.mount
```

Within each of these files contains the mount instructions and snap file it is going to mount.

```
terrance@terrance-ubuntu:/etc/systemd/system$ cat snap-bitwarden-85.mount 
[Unit]
Description=Mount unit for bitwarden, revision 85
After=snapd.mounts-pre.target
Before=snapd.mounts.target
Before=local-fs.target

[Mount]
What=/var/lib/snapd/snaps/bitwarden_85.snap
Where=/snap/bitwarden/85
Type=squashfs
Options=nodev,ro,x-gdu.hide,x-gvfs-hide
LazyUnmount=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=snapd.mounts.target
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The easiest way since you are not going to use snaps anymore would be to go to that directory and remove all of the `.mount` files.

```
cd /etc/systemd/system
sudo rm -Rf snap*
```

I chose the `sudo rm -Rf snap*` command because there is another sub-directory also containing `.mount` files and since they all start with the word snap, that should cover them all.

After those files are gone you shouldn't see the mount errors anymore.